# Is there a Drupal module to display various flags in a list of contents?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, backend

I am a PM working on a new back office for several media clients. In current back-end of my customer, they use a table ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD7Vx.jpg)) where the last column display some custom flags, toggled on and off according to various criterias.

For example, the red flag can mean something like "wokflow state is Ready to be published", but the blue flag can mean "created less than two days ago", and the green flag can mean "author is not a journalist but a reader"...

I never saw a Drupal interface with that sort of feature, but maybe there is an existing module who does that ?

Thanks anyway for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Think that could be implemented just by using a regular taxonomy with tags (and colours associated with those tags).

If you need to toggle the flags dynamically through the interface then you might want to have a look at the [flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) which allows you to do just that.